# From which version does Bash drop privileges?

Tags: bash, shell, system-calls, version, privileges

I've been trying to do some buffer overflow attack, and I thought I could use `system("/bin/bash")` in order to obtain a root shell.

Then I read [the documentation for `system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

It says:

> `system()` will not, in fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges on systems on which `/bin/sh` is bash version 2, since bash 2 drops privileges on startup.

The system I am attacking has a bash version 4.3, and when I use a `system("/bin/bash")`, I don't get root privileges (of course the initial program I am attacking starts with root privileges). My question is: will system drop privileges only on bash version 2, or will it drop them for any bash that has a version > 2?

EDIT: `/bin/bash` just drops privileges, while `/bin/dash` or `/bin/sh` don't.

After reading comments from @StéphaneChazelas, EDIT2:

- **check [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1215660) for more explanation and accuracy about bash dropping privileges.**
- `-p` option can be used to be sure to keep privileges when the bash spawns.

Comment: Your title says `/bin/sh`, but your code says `/bin/bash`. Which one is it?  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209215/bin-sh-does-not-drop-privileges

Comment: Depends on the system as well as Debian for instance used to revert that behaviour with a patch for sh IIRC. Note that you can use `bash -p` to keep your euid/egid, but that would help if they have been dropped by the shell called by `system()` itself beforehand.

Comment: @Kusalananda So the system does drop privileges on a /bin/bash right?

Comment: (sorry, it should be _that would **not** help_ in my comment about)

Comment: @Kusalananda post an answer to this post so I can mark this as solved.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1215660

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Current version

Recent versions of bash will drop privileges, unless it was started with `-p`.    From the section of [bash(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) describing the privileged mode:

> If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the **-p** option is not supplied, [...] the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the **-p** option is supplied at startup, the effective user id is not reset. Turning this option off causes the effective user and group ids to be set to the real user and group ids.

## Historical versions

You asked "From which version...?".  The part of `system()` that you quote has been unchanged since the earliest revision available in the active git repository [(version 1.70)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/man3/system.3?id=fea681dafb1363a154b7fc6d59baa83d2a9ebc5c).  That was checked in in 2004, and the comments indicate it was last modified in 2001.

[Bash version 3 was released in 2004](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).  That means that bash 2 would have been the current/latest version at the time.  So effectively, it's saying "...bash version 2 or higher/newer", ie. this has been the case *since* version 2.

To confirm for yourself, you could try to build some intermediate versions and test them, or consult the bash [git repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?id=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071#n503).  The lines responsible are:

```
  if (running_setuid && privileged_mode == 0)
    disable_priv_mode ();
```

Those have been there since [version 2.0](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?id=ccc6cda312fea9f0468ee65b8f368e9653e1380b#n350).  Looking back to [version 1.14.7](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/flags.c?id=726f63884db0132f01745f1fb4465e6621088ccf#n241), bash would only drop privileges when privileged mode was explicitly disabled with `+p`:

```
    case 'p':
      if (on_or_off == '+')
      {
        setuid (current_user.uid);
        setgid (current_user.gid);
        current_user.euid = current_user.uid;
        current_user.egid = current_user.gid;
      }
```